# How to enable new table option in oracle sql developer tool

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create table automatically using new table option in oracle SQL developer,but that option is disabled in my tool.

Can any one please help me out in this issue.

Please find the below image highlighted with red mark for your better understanding.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To quote [Jeff Smitth](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-supports-db2-sybase-mysql-access-and-teradata/):

> SQL Developer is built by Oracle, for Oracle. It’s the database IDE.
>   ...
>   But, SQL Developer is also ... a 3rd party database migration platform.
>   ...
>   Since we support migrations from these other database platforms, wouldn’t it be neat if SQL Developer could connect and query those 3rd party databases too? Surprise, surprise – that’s exactly what we DO do today.
>
> **What ‘Support’ means**
>
> You can connect to, browse, and query (SELECTs only) SQL Server, DB2, Access, MySQL, and Teradata.
>
> **What ‘Support’ does NOT mean**
>
> - providing debuggers
> - delivering database administration features
> - write access to the database
>
> Sound a little harsh or spartan? Going much further in any of these areas would just open a big ole can of worms, and we’re committed to providing an optimal experience for the Oracle database. But, since we already support these limited features, there’s no real reason to hide it.

That post is from 2012, but as far as I'm aware is still mostly true.

Since creating tables would count as write access and a DBA feature, it isn't a matter of enabling the option for your MySQL database, it isn't supported. This is an area of functionality that only applies to Oracle databases. (Even though Oracle Corp. owns MySQL... this means the Oracle RDBMS).